# jQuery plugin throwing "TypeError" outside of noConflict mode?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, wordpress, datatables

I'm trying to insert a **DataTables** Editor-based table into a WordPress page (seen [here](http://dcturanoinc.com/blog/contacts/)), and I'm running into the following error: **`TypeError: f[("editor_" + c)] is undefined`**

What's puzzling about this is that I used `jQuery(function ($) {` to get out of `noConflict` mode, yet this issue is still occuring.

Any ideas why?

This is the jQuery I'm using to build the table:

```
jQuery(function ($) {
    $( document ).ready(function(e) {
        var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
            "ajaxUrl": "../wp-content/plugins/contacts/php/table.wp_contacts.php",
            "domTable": "#wp_contacts",
            "fields": [
                {
                    "label": "Contact",
                    "name": "contact",
                    "type": "text"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Company",
                    "name": "company",
                    "type": "text"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Email",
                    "name": "email",
                    "type": "text"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Phone",
                    "name": "phone",
                    "type": "text"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Fax",
                    "name": "fax",
                    "type": "text"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Tax ID",
                    "name": "tax_id",
                    "type": "text"
                },
                {
                    "label": "Address",
                    "name": "address",
                    "type": "text"
                }
            ]
        } );
        $('#wp_contacts').dataTable( {
            "sDom": "Tfrtip",
            "sAjaxSource": "../wp-content/plugins/contacts/php/table.wp_contacts.php",
            "aoColumns": [
                {
                    "mData": "contact"
                },
                {
                    "mData": "company"
                },
                {
                    "mData": "email"
                },
                {
                    "mData": "phone"
                },
                {
                    "mData": "fax"
                },
                {
                    "mData": "tax_id"
                },
                {
                    "mData": "address"
                }
            ],
            "oTableTools": {
                "sRowSelect": "multi",
                "aButtons": [
                    { "sExtends": "editor_create", "editor": editor },
                    { "sExtends": "editor_edit",   "editor": editor },
                    { "sExtends": "editor_remove", "editor": editor }
                ]
            }
        } );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found out that TableTools needed to be loaded before Editor. Once that "wp_enqueue_script" was called for TableTools before Editor, everything worked.